# Logging in express server on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have deployed my node application on heroku. I setup my express server to start logging using morgain in a 'logs' directory.

(Although the code is not really relevant to see, I am presenting it below:)

```
console.log('************* RUNNING in PRODUCTION ************ *');

var logDirectory = __dirname + '/../logs';
// ensure log directory exists
fs.existsSync(logDirectory) || fs.mkdirSync(logDirectory);

morgan.token('id', function getId(req) {
  return req.id;
});

// create a rotating write stream
var accessLogStream = FileStreamRotator.getStream({
  filename: logDirectory + '/access-%DATE%.log',
  frequency: 'daily',
  verbose: false
});

// setup the logger
app.use(assignId);
app.use(morgan('combined', {stream: accessLogStream}));
app.use(morgan(':id :method :url :response-time'));
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/../build/images/favicon.ico'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../build'));
```

so far so good.. however I noticed a strange thing.. 
that I had no way to ssh'ing into heroku to open up the logs directory and read the log files..

In short.. is there a way to ssh into my heroku deployment.. I have spent too many hours looking for this ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just add the apps [papertrail](http://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/hosting-services/heroku)
Or [logentries](https://logentries.com/doc/heroku/)

You can easily retiree the logs with

```
heroku logs
```

Accessing from your toolbelt [reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging)

And you will not have access via `ssh` in you **heroku deployment**.

Comment: so then is there a point of using morgain and writing log files to an external directory ?

Comment: Well you gonna need a third party app for that.

Comment: @SMV Was that helpful? Good enough to correct answer ?